# Regex - stack trace - match all numbers except java class line number

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm stuck trying to come up with a regex to match a pattern in java stack trace. This regex should identify all numbers in a string except the line number corresponding to the java class.

For example

```
str = "(SomeName.java:470) This is the 1st string out of a total of 50 string:345"
```

I want to write a regex which identifies 1, 50 and 345 and not 470.

I came up with one but it quite doesn't does it for me - `"(?<!.java:)[\d]*"`.

This gets 70 instead of 470 and the reason is self explanatory.

Can you please help me with modifying the above regex to match the pattern from the example?

Comment: 1 should also count. Sorry that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
\d+(?![^(]*\))
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/9

If you have data like `34)` the use

```
^\([^)]*\)|(\d+)
```

and grab the captures or groups.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oE6jJ1/11

Comment: I tried modifying the test string say if I have a ) after a number that is not taken into account. Say at the end if there is :345) 345 is getting ignored. Wanted to let you know. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your lookbehind assertion as follows.

```
(?<!java:)\b\d+
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/gP7jH5/2)

Comment: If you have a digit following a non-word boundary, you can use `(?<!java:)(?<!\d)\d+` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Java code:

```
String str1 = "(SomeName.java:470) This is the 1st string out of a total of 50 string:345";
String regex1 = "(?<!java:)\\b\\d+";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex1).matcher(str1);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (m.find()) {
    sb.append(" "+str1.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```